# FreePascal/Lazarus: Why are contents of binary files seen?

Tags: lazarus

I'm using a typed file with this record format:

```
  KClientServerConfType = Record
    HostName: String[255];
    DatabaseName: String[200];
    UserName: String[200];
    Password: String[200];
  end;
```

It works fine. But how come I can read the contents of the file using GEdit? I recognise the values amidst garbled text. Is this normal or should it be non-readable?

Here's the code to write:

```
  AssignFile(ThisFile, 'clientserver.conf');
  Rewrite(ThisFile);
  Settings.HostName:= '192.168.100.100';
  Settings.DatabaseName:= 'dbESM';
  Settings.UserName:= 'itsols';
  Settings.Password:= 'pass12d3';
  Write(ThisFile, Settings);
  CloseFile(ThisFile);
```

I'm using Lazarus on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As far as the RTL is concerned, it is normal.

Comment: If FPC's handling of shortstrings is similar to Delphi's, then the probable reason is that what you're seeing includes the length byte of each string (e.g. the value at HostName[0]) and random data between the actual length of each string and its declared length, e.g HostName[16] ... HostName[200] if your Settings variable is a local variable.

Comment: Hmmm... I was under the impression that String[255] is the MAX limit and the field would adjust as per the data. I was wrong again :/

Comment: @MartynA So if I wanted to make the data in my file unreadable by an editor, is encryption/encoding the only way?

Comment: @itsols: Yes, I would think so.  Btw "the field would adjust as per the data": it would if you were writing to a plain text file, but if you're using a "File of ClientServerConfType", you'll get the []0 bytes in the file as well as the junk beyond the strings' dynamic lengths.

Comment: Perhaps someone should put these into an answer... Quite helpful tips in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If FPC's handling of shortstrings is similar to Delphi's, then the probable reason is that what you're seeing includes the length byte of each string (e.g. the value at HostName[0]) and random data between the actual length of each string and its declared length, e.g HostName[16] ... HostName[200] if your Settings variable is a local variable; if it is a local variable, the random stuff is just whatever was previously in memory prior to your variable.

"the field would adjust as per the data": (in Delphi) it would if you were writing to a plain text file, but if you're using a "File of ClientServerConfType", you'll get the [0] bytes in the file as well as the junk beyond the strings' dynamic lengths.

There may be extra, probably junk-filled, padding between the record fields in the file if the record isn't declared as "packed".

Comment: But aren't strings packed by default? I only recall having to specify PACKED back in 1990.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea about Packed in FPC.  ISTR modern Delphi tends to unpacked records by default, to align record fields on optimal boundaries for CPU access speed.

Comment: itols: The strings are packed, but the records not. On FPC it depends on mode (IOW TP mode has TP's defaults, 32-bit Delphi mode has 32-bit Delphi's defaults as long as it doesn't clash with the architecture. 64-bit FPC is older than 64-bit Delphi so that might not be backwards compat with delphi because of backwards compat with older FPC versions